# Will there a difference in performance when a server (httpd or mysql) by building it from sources vs installing it using yum/apt repositories?

Tags: mysql, lamp

I have a web app on the LAMP architecture. Right now all the servers are installed from the binaries available in the platform repositories (apt / yum). However, I think it would be best to install the servers by building them from the source and then installing them.

Will the second method have any significant advantages over the former? Disadvantages that I can think of is the manual maintenance.

Comment: Found this link on ServerFault:
http://serverfault.com/questions/179040/installing-mysql-from-source-or-using-apt-get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For e. g. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/compile-and-link-options.html to quote:

> - If you link dynamically (without -static), the result is 13% slower on Linux.
>     Note that you still can use a dynamically linked MySQL library for your client applications. It is the server that is most critical for performance.

So, in general answer is "there will".

Answer (score 1):

The advantages should be minimum unless you're hitting a specific situation where compiler optimizations would help you. My personal opinion is that it's not worth the extra work and, if you're on a support contract for you base OS, it would invalidate it.

As always, I suggest you to carefully benchmark your compiled version and the vanilla package in a controlled environment.

Comment: But what if the the server is the lifeline of the application.